# Why is the Debug.WriteLine Not Working in Asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, output, visual-studio-debugging

I have created a new Asp.net project to try to get information from the Pokemon API site.  I created the basic model and added a scaffolded controller based on it.  My plan was to use the httpclient class to get a response and test if it worked by logging the result to Debug.WriteLine.  However, not only does this not show up in the output, I added a simple text message and even that won't show up.  I have done all this in the Index method of the controller:

```
namespace PokeWebProj.Controllers
{
    public class PokemonsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly PokeWebProjContext _context;

        public PokemonsController(PokeWebProjContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }


        // GET: Pokemons
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            //HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            //HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/bulbasaur");
            //JsonResult pokeJson = Json(response.Content);
            //string pokeString = response.Content.ToString();
            Debug.WriteLine("Test Message");
            //Debug.Write(pokeString);
            return View(await _context.Pokemon.ToListAsync());
        }
.
.
.
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?  I have the response code commented out for now because I just want to find out how the Debug.Writeline works first.  I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Where are you looking for this message, in the Output panel, or the launched terminal?

Comment: I am looking for it in the panel that says "Output", below which is "Show output from:" and I have selected "Debug".

Comment: Are you sure this Index method is getting called?

Comment: No I'm not sure its getting called.  I am very new to Asp.net and C#.

Comment: Its not showing up when I put in the program.cs file either.

Comment: You've compiled for DEBUG?

Comment: Yes, I ran it in debugging mode.

Comment: Not sure myself, but this page [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.defaulttracelistener?view=net-6.0) says: "To enable debugging in C#, add the /d:DEBUG flag to the compiler command line when you compile your code, or add #define DEBUG to the top of your file."

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it.